# Really popular question? Or somebody taking advantage of a loophole?

Tags: support, views

[How to test if a file is a directory in a batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138981/how-do-i-test-if-a-file-is-a-directory-in-a-batch-script)

[Why am I getting tree conflicts in Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738367/why-am-i-getting-tree-conflicts-in-subversion)

Both of these questions are 5 minutes old, if even that, and they have 3k and 10k views. I just finally got the "Popular Question" badge (1k views on your question) and that took several months... What's up?

EDIT:

I messed up... they were editted 5 minutes before I saw them. I was looking at a "last modified" timestamp instead of the timestamp of when it was asked.

Comment: Which tab are you looking at? On the homepage's active tab, the timestamp doesn't reflect when the question was asked, but the last activity. If you're on the questions tab, then it will say "asked ___ ago".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

5 minutes old? One is "asked Apr 10 '09 at 17:57", the other "asked Sep 26 '08 at 11:57". They've had whole *years* to accumulate views. Given both have 8 answers, they were fairly active in their prime and probably are fairly easy questions to run into on a search.

They both, though, happen to have been [bumped recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738367/why-am-i-getting-tree-conflicts-in-subversion/3728710#3728710) [by relatively new users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138981/how-do-i-test-if-a-file-is-a-directory-in-a-batch-script/3728742#3728742). It'll result in an increase in visibility on the front page, but I wouldn't even compare any views from this recent activity to what has simply drifted in over the course of time.

Comment: Wow, I should have looked at the dates, but when they appeared in the questions list, it was labeled "5m" and "10m." Is that because they were edited 5 and 10 minutes ago?

Comment: @Corey Those times were their last activity, yes. You're probably on either Active sort or the front page, which both show "modified" timestamps of the last activity rather than "asked" timestamps of the original posting.

Comment: My fault then, I jumped to a conclusion. I didn't realize that edits would do that. My stupidity

Comment: @Corey No worries. It's important to be vigilant.

Comment: I had just worked hard for my 1k views, and I was under the impression they received it in 5m by what I thought was some tech douchebaggery, but that's what I get for jumping the gun and taking it personally.

Comment: This questions are related to problems very many number of users deals with.

Espetially I'm not supprised the this about SVN merge is so popular. Almost everyone I know that have been using merge have problems with it.